# how to add QDockWidget to QFrame in PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qdockwidget, dockable

How do I add `QDockWidget` to `QFrame` ? since QFrame does not have `addDockWidget` !!!

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

app = QApplication( sys.argv )

qmainwin = QFrame()
#qmainwin.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
s = QWidget()
vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout( )

spin1 = QSpinBox()
vboxlayout.addWidget( spin1 )

spin2 = QSpinBox()
vboxlayout.addWidget( spin2 )
s.setLayout( vboxlayout )

qdock = QDockWidget( )
qdock.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
qdock.setWidget( s )
qmainwin.addDockWidget( Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, qdock )
qmainwin.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using `QFrame` instead of `QMainWindow`?

Comment: i made a GUI application using `QFrame` and everything worked fine later i discovered the need of some detachable part of the GUI, now that I have too many layouts i wanted to see if their is any quick way of doing it.

Comment: It'd be relatively easy to convert `QFrame` to `QMainWindow`. At least, much more easier than putting dockable widgets to `QFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? I added the `QDockWidget` to an `QLayout` and then set the layout of the `QFrame`.

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Panel |
                QtGui.QFrame.Plain)

        label = QtGui.QLabel('This is random text')

        dockWidget = QtGui.QDockWidget('Main', self)
        # set the widget to non-movable, non-floatable and non-closable
        dockWidget.setFeatures(dockWidget.NoDockWidgetFeatures)
        dockWidget.setWidget(label)

        # add the QDockWidget to the QLayout
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(dockWidget)

        # set the layout of the QFrame
        frame.setLayout(hbox)

        # create another QLayout to add QFrame
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(frame)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: that is neat, thanks!!! is there any way we can disable the close button of the docking widget?

Comment: The only way I know how to do that is by setting the features of `QDockWidget` to `NoDockWidgetFeatures` and thus to non-floatable, non-movable and non-closeable. This seems logical, since if you can detach the dock widget from your window, you might want to close it as well. I updated my answer, so take a look.

Comment: that takes away the point of having floating window then can't we use `QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint ` like its possible in `QFrame`?